# Override Controller Function Magento 2

Tags: php, controller, overriding, magento2

I want to override execute Function from Magento 2 CreatePost.php

File : `Magento/Controller/Account/CreatePost.php`

MyFile : `Company/Module/Controller/Account/CreatePost.php`

File:

```
namespace Company\Module\Controller\Account;

class CreatePost extends \Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\CreatePost
{
    public function execute()
    {
          // Override standard class code
    }
}
```

File: `di.xml`

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">

 <preference for="Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\CreatePost" type="Company\Module\Controller\Account\CreatePost" />

</config>
```

When i try to register a new customer i am just getting a white page with no errors or something

Comment: have you customize any function in your file , may be that is causing some issue , Please check log once. Thanks

Comment: Did you check magento log or error log? I had also override the controller in the same way and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Blank page is normal behaviour because you didn't add any functionality to execution().

Try this:

```
namespace Company\Module\Controller\Account;

class CreatePost extends     \Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\CreatePost
{
    public function execute()
    {
          // your code
          parent::execute();
    }
}
```

Moreover I would recommend to add a dependency on Magento_Customer module in module.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
<module name="Company_Module" setup_version="1.0.0">
    <sequence>
        <module name="Magento_Customer"/>
    </sequence>
</module>
```

Comment: I was experiencing the same white page of death issue and the answer is really simple. It's not enough to do `parent::execute()`, you need to return the redirectResult returned from the parent method (i.e.,  `return parent::execute();`)

Comment: return parent::execute(); is working for me. Thanks